# How do I check if anything other than an integer is in my variable?

Tags: python

So I am still coding my game and I am on the last bit of valiation.

I need to know how I can check if there are any characters other than an integer in my variable.

Here is how my code looks like right now.

```
import random
random = random.randint(1001,10000)
random = str(random)
print(random)

count = 0


while True:
  correct = 0
  count = count + 1
  guess = input("Guess a random 4 digit number")
 #guess = str(guess)

if guess != str(guess):

if len(guess) == 4:


  for i in range(4):
    if guess[i] == random[i]:
        correct = correct + 1


  if guess == random:
      print("Well done you guessed the number correctly in", count, "tries")
      break
  else:
    print("Wrong you got", correct, "correct")

else:
  print("Must Be A 4 Digit Number!")
else:
  print("It Must Be A Number!")
```

If you were to paste this code it would be wrong because of indentation.

Thanks,

Comment: I think you need to describe your problem better. What variable? And you just want to know if a string can be parsed as a number?

Comment: What I mean is when I input (guess) and it is not an integer I want to be able to print out saying "It must be a number!"

Answer (score 1):

try isdigit() method for strings:

```
'123213'.isdigit()
True

'123213dsd'.isdigit()
False
```

Comment: I don't know how to use this properly

Comment: if guess.isdigit() == False: print "It must be a number!"